# Vite not resolving file path when passed into function

Tags: flutter, bundle, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, vite

I am using Vite to bundle an application, and in the index.html of one of my subpages, I have a function as follows:

```
var scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
scriptTag.src = "main.dart.js"; // change to app
scriptTag.type = "application/javascript"; // change to app
document.body.append(scriptTag);
```

Which gives the following error in the web console:

```
 http://localhost:5000/app/main.dart.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
n @ app.e9ec45f4.js:1
(anonymous) @ app.e9ec45f4.js:1
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ app.e9ec45f4.js:1
load (async)
(anonymous) @ app.e9ec45f4.js:1
```

Vite is not resolving this paths. I am assuming this is because Vite recognizes them as string inputs to a function and not a reference to a file. **Is there any way to get Vite to resolve paths that are used in non-import functions?**

Below are the relevant files in my directory structure:

```
src:
- index.html
- app:
   - index.html
   - main.dart.js
```

Here is my vite.config.js:

```
export default defineConfig({
    root: "src",
    publicDir: "../public",
    build: {
        emptyOutDir: true,
        outDir: "../dist/web",
        rollupOptions: {
            input: {
                main: "src/index.html",
                app: "src/app/index.html",
            },
            external: ["assets", "splash/style.css"],
        },
        // optimizeDeps: {
        //  exclude: ["app/flutter_service_worker.js"],
        // },
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue: "vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js",
        },
    },
    define: {
        "process.env": process.env,
    },
    plugins: [
        VitePWA({
            strategies: "injectManifest",
            srcDir: "app",
            filename: "flutter_service_worker.js",
            injectRegister: "null",
        }),
    ],
});
```

Thanks